# GCP BigQuery wont access a single partition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm experiencing a problem with a GBQ query which goes through all the data in a table, even though the table is partitioned.

The partitioning is set to `DAY` on the `datetime` field.

Currently the query I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE datetime = "2023-09-11"
```

The `datetime` field is a TIMESTAMP, so I tried it like this: `date(datetime) = "2023-09-11"` and it still wanted to access all 3GB of data, every time.

I played around with `DATE_TRUNC()` function, but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you try the opposite? To parse the "2023-09-11" in Timestamp? But it should not affect the result. Are you sure that you have data in different partition? Are you sure about the partitioning config and field?

Comment: I'm sure of the partitioning configuration and field. And I did try the opposite with timestamp. Didn't fix the issue :/

Comment: You should share more, a minimal amount of code to reproduce your issue. At least the DDL of your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning for small tables won't improve the performance or reduce the cost that's why they are offering clustering instead of partitioning for these kind of tables.

```
Consider clustering a table instead of partitioning a table in the following circumstances:
Partitioning results in a small amount of data per partition (approximately less than 10 GB)
```

Comment: For some reason I wasn't able to find the information you presented in your answer being described in the GCP documentation. Could you provide a source of said data?

Comment: you can see it there:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: It's true, and there won't be optimization. But the processed data should differ with or without partition.